# Thrown security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException whon unkown http api get called or any other runtime exception raised

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I implemented the spring security with jwt token here is the code
JwtUtils class:

```
@Component
public class JwtUtils {

    private static final Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtUtils.class);

    @Value("${atlokal.userMgmt.app.jwtSecret}")
    private String jwtSecret;

    @Value("${atlokal.userMgmt.app.jwtExpirationMs}")
    private int jwtExpirationMs;

    public String generateJwtToken(Authentication authentication) {

        UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject((userPrincipal.getUsername()))
                .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
                .addClaims(addCustomClaims(userPrincipal))
                .signWith(key(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    private Key key() {
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Decoders.BASE64.decode(jwtSecret));
    }
    public boolean validateJwtToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build().parse(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            logger.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key()).build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }
    private Map<String, Object> addCustomClaims(UserDetailsImpl userPrincipal) {
        Map<String, Object> customClaims=new HashMap<>();
        List< UserRoleResponse> userRoleResponse =userPrincipal.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(userRole-> {
                    UserRoleResponse roleResponse=new UserRoleResponse();
                    roleResponse.setName(userRole.getAuthority());
                    return roleResponse;
                }).toList();
        customClaims.put("userRoles", userRoleResponse);
        return customClaims;
    }
}
```

AuthEntryPointJwt class:

```
@Component
public class AuthEntryPointJwt implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPointJwt.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;
    
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException)
            throws IOException {
        resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, authException);
    }

}
```

AuthTokenFilter class:

```
    private static final Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                userDetails,
                                null,
                                userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public String claimUserEmailId(HttpServletRequest request){
       return jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(parseJwt(request));
    }
    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfigure class without SecuritywebAdapter:

```
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigure {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();

        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                                auth.requestMatchers("/user").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                );
        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer(){
        return (web)->web.ignoring()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/user/register")
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/auth/signin");
    }

}
```

if you observe I excluded the below APIs from the spring security and those are working fine

"/user/register"
"/auth/signin"

but when I try to hit an unknown URL that does not exist in the application I am getting 401
error instead of method not found error even if I handle common rest exceptions in controller advice like below.

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<APIError> handle(MethodArgumentNotValidException exception) {
        List<ErrorDetails> errorDetailsList=exception.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors()
                .stream().map(fieldError -> new ErrorDetails(fieldError.getDefaultMessage(),fieldError.getField()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(APIError.createInstance(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString(),
                errorDetailsList), null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BadRequestException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<APIError> handle(BadRequestException ex){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(APIError.createInstance(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.toString(),
                List.of(new ErrorDetails(ex.getMessage(),null))), null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UserNotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<APIError> handle(UserNotFoundException ex){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(APIError.createInstance(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString(),
                List.of(new ErrorDetails(ex.getMessage(),null))), null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<APIError> handle(NoHandlerFoundException ex){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(APIError.createInstance(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString(),
                List.of(new ErrorDetails(ex.getMessage(),null))), null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler({ AuthenticationException.class })
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<APIError> handleAuthenticationException(Exception ex) {

        APIError re = APIError.createInstance(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.toString(),
                List.of(new ErrorDetails(ErrorMessageCodes.INVALID_AUTHENTICATION,null)));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(re);
    }
}
```

but it is not pinking the NoHandlerFoundException handle method in runtime.
and always I am getting a 401 error even for any runtime exception. and
in the console I am getting common exception which is mentioned in below:

**WARN 11160 --- [nio-8080-exec-7]
.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver :
Resolved [org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException:
Full authentication is required to access this resource]**

I wanted to respond with a method not found error if we hit with an unknown API URL and if the API comes under the security it should ask for the valid jwt token if the vaid tokent provided needs to give the successful response otherwise throw 401 error. can you help me to fix this issue?

Comment: You are aware that this implementation is not recommended, as it is insecure and is not at all documented in the spring security docs. You have followed some poorly written blog that has no idea how jwts should be used as they should never be handed out to browsers. I suggest that if you want to learn spring security and security in general you read the official docs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and if you have any idea why I am all ways getting 401 errors for unknown APIs please tell me. Thank you

Comment: please implement security correctly, then i will assist.

Comment: could you please tell me where went wrong in the above implementation. I used the spring security 6.1.2 version and how can you finalize it is not a secure implementation. If you give me some information it will help me to learn more. Thank you

Comment: Im sorry, but didnt you read my first comment? Its says right there, read the official spring documentation.